# React native element position?

Tags: react-native

How can I positioning this elements?

[image: Elements: Line and Circles]

here is my code:

```
return (
<View style={rootViewStyle}>
  <View style={lineStyle} />
  <View style={faceContainerStyle}>
    <View style={faceStyle} />
    <View style={faceStyle} />
    <View style={faceStyle} />
    <View style={faceStyle} />
  </View>

</View>
```

StyleSheet:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  rootViewStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
  },
  faceContainerStyle: {
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  faceStyle: {
    height: 50,
    width: 50,
    borderRadius: 25,
    backgroundColor: '#ffc700',
  },
  lineStyle: {
    borderBottomWidth: 2,
    borderBottomColor: '#c0c0c0',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add 2 more properties (`position` and `top` ) to `lineStyle` as follows

```
lineStyle: {
  position: 'relative',
  top: 26,
  borderBottomWidth: 2,
  borderBottomColor: '#c0c0c0',
},
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: As you can see, I have `position` this element to `relative`, now the height of the parent view depends on the height of the `faceStyle` which is `50`, that's why I make it `faceStyle.height / 2 - borderBottomWidth /2`, actually it will be `24` instead of `26`.